# Normalizable eigenvectors of the inverted harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, hamiltonian

Consider the inverted harmonic potential $V(x) = - x^2 $. Does the corresponding Hamiltonian

$$ H = p^2 - x^2 $$

have any normalizable eigenstate?  How about

$$ H = p^2 - x^4  ? $$

Any good reference on this kind of problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16299/84132, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46289/84132
There's also this article https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0703234v1 and references within. For the second part, I'd say the same reasoning applies since the hamiltonian is unbounded from below, hence the eingenstates won't be in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and won't be normalizable.